# How to use a function with input

Tags: function, input

I have a book inbound but I really want to do this.
Can you explainhow I need to go about to use the value I input to go through the function? And then print it out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int addition(int a, int b)
{

    int sum;
        sum = a + b;
    return sum;

}

int main() {

    int a;
    int b;

    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;



    cout << addition(a,b) << endl;

    system("pause");
    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Add a tag to say what language you are using.